# I Have 3 Entity (User, Trainer, Admin). Do you think I need the baseUser repository?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to build an example application like Udemy. And i have 3 entities (User, Trainer, Admin). I try to make my application according to some conditions that I mentioned below

- Users can pay for and purchase the course (Enroll). Non-user instructors and admins cannot buy training.

As I said before, I have 3 Entities and 3 Repositories. I have tried two ways to solve it, both successful, but I can't choose which is the best use.

- The first way is separating entities. By doing so, when there is no user in the user repository with userId, I am sure that this userId does not correspond to a user or that it is not a user (it can be trainer or admin or none of them)
- The second way is inheritance. I created a BaseUser class

```
public abstract class BaseUser extends BaseEntity {
private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EUserRole role;

}
```

and I created BaseUserRepository that UserRepository, AdminRepository, and TrainerRepository inherit.

```
public interface BaseUserRepository<T extends BaseUser> extends JpaRepository<T, UUID> { }
```

and I have used this repository in my enrollment service.

```
User user = baseUserRepository.findById(userId)
       .filter(u -> u.getRole() == EUserRole.USER)
       .map(u -> (User) u)
       .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User not found or not authorized"));
```

Which method do you think I should use? I am so confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the principles of programming and system flexibility, then for similar entities with common properties it is always better to have a parent, and in this case, in fact, all three entities are users, I would advise using the base class, since in the future this can help make the system more flexible (for example, changing the user's password, changing the name, and so on)